# How to disable multiple requests per socket in NSURLSession?

Tags: ios, http, networking, nsurlsession, amazon-elb

I'm doing batch upload and using NSURLSession to do it in background.
Up until iOS9 all went well, but iOS10 has a different behavior:

**If I queue 100 POST requests, it will batch them all to same socket**.

So all the 100 requests happen in parallel on same socket, and timeouts after a few minutes.

On the server side we're using AWS ELB, and I'm guessing I could disable this behavior from requests headers / ELB Settings. The server itself is node.js. Suggestions?

**Edit:**

[Http header `Connection: keep-alive`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) might be it.
But I can't change it, I see it gets overridden from `close` back to `keep-alive` using Charles proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually we've worked around this issue using the http header [`Connection`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection).

iOS uses its `Keep-Alive` option, meaning you can send multiple requests on the same socket. Neither turning off pipelining, nor setting the header value could remove it. iOS forces it. **So we ended up removing it from the server's response**. It caused iOS to open a new socket per request.

That way it we got back to a number of connection matching the number `NSURLSession`'s. Allowing us to upload a bunch of large files in background on iOS 10 & 11's beta.

Answer (score 0):

In theory?  Either:

- Use multiple sessions.  NSURLSession does not share connections across session boundaries.
- Use an external queue (e.g. NSOperationQueue) to limit the number of concurrent requests that you add to a single session.

For background uploads, probably the only option is the first one.  Note that you should *not* send each request to a separate session, as you'll end up with lots of unnecessary overhead from TLS negotiation, etc.  Just keep the number of requests per session to something sane.

However, I doubt either of those approaches will help you.  Whether it is one socket or ten, the problem you're hitting is that either the cellular network isn't able to hold a connection open that long reliably or Amazon's servers/routers aren't willing to do so.

So the real fix almost certainly involves proper retry logic.

But I'm a little confused when you say "in parallel on the same socket".  That isn't possible unless HTTP pipelining is enabled, which AFAIK it is not by default, even in iOS 10.  Be sure you didn't turn it on by mistake.

Comment: Thanks! It appears that it happens even if I make sure pipelining is off. Also, it seems like iOS internal bug, as it wasn't happening on iOS9. Eventually we've figured out we can workaround when not allowing http keep-alive. I'll add a full answer